# How to get range from list, For given list generate range

Tags: scala

In Scala, how do I get range from a `List`? For example I know that

```
scala> 1990 until 2011 toList
```

will generate

```
List(1990, 1991, 1992, /* snip */ 2008, 2009, 2010)
```

I want the reverse, if I give a list, I want the range to be generated.

Is there a way to convert a list of strings to ranges

For example if the given string list is `{"100", "101", "102", "10005", "10006", "10008", "10010"}` a string `"100-102, 10005-10006, 10008,1010"` is generated.

For a list `{"A129", "A130", "A199", "A200", "A999", "B000", "B001"}`, `"A129-A130,A199-A200,A999-B001"` is generated

Comment: The answer to "is there a way..." is certainly "yes", this is not going to be classified under the category of "unsolvable problems".  However, you haven't given us enough information.  I wouldn't have suspected that B000 was the immediate successor of A999, without a lot of information that you have held back from us.  This seems like a case where you should be providing us with "here's what I tried" and "here's where I'm stuck".

Comment: Requirement is for the list >>> For a list {"A129", "A130", "A199", "A200", "A999", "B000", "B001"} Output is >>>>> "A129-A130,A199-A200,A999-B001" is generated.....Yes you are right stew, B000 is immediate successor of A999.